# Parse simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

Hi have a sample data and I want to extract responseMessage from this.
`var_dump($response) which print something like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (3) { <br>
  ["responseMessage"]=><br>
  string(25) "Processing was completed."<br>
  ["responseStatus"]=><br>
  string(7) "SUCCESS"<br>
  ["processInstances"]=><br>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) {<br>
    ["processInstance"]=><br>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#32 (1) {<br>
      ["id"]=><br>
      string(8) "87921091"<br>
    }<br>
  }<br>
}
```

now I am trying to do somthing like this `$response->responseMessage`
Which is returning

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#34 (1) {<br>
  [0]=><br>
  string(25) "Processing was completed."<br>
} <br>
```

NB : this is the result of a `var_dump()`
Please help!! I just need this responseMessage string.

Comment: Isn't `$response->responseMessage` what you want? `Processing was completed.` is the message, no?

Comment: Show the actual XML.

Comment: `$response->responseMessage` will return a SimpleXMLElement as you see, if you want the text from it you can just cast it to a string `(string)$response->responseMessage`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **SimpleXMLElement**

Example :

```
...
<responseMessage>
<responseStatus></responseStatus>
<processInstances></processInstances>
</responseMessage>
```

Using **SimpleXMLElement**

```
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $xmlObject->responseStatus;
```

Hope this help you.